# Group by LINQ using a list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I would like to create a generic `LINQ` function to group a result from a `select` in my database. However, for each database table, I should have a `group by` different. Basically, what I am trying to do is
group the result from `table1` by `columnName1` and `columnName2`:

```
from element in databaseRows
     group element by 
          new { column1 => element.Value("columnName1"), column2 => element.Value("columnName2")}
          into g
          select new { key = g.Key, value = g };
```

And group the result from `table2` by `columnName3`:

```
from element in databaseRows
     group element by 
          new { column1 => element.Value("columnName3")}
          into g
          select new { key = g.Key, value = g };
```

I want to create a generic function that receives a list of columns that it has to group by like this:

```
from element in databaseRows
     group element by 
          new { 
               foreach (var v in columnsList)
                      element.Value(v);
          }
          into g
          select new { key = g.Key, value = g };
```

I know that I can't do in this way, but is there another way to do it?

Comment: are you using _linq-to-sql_ or _entity framework_, or is `databaseRows` a collection that you've already loaded from the database?  the answer to this question will affect what you are able to do

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri, in my system, there is a class called DbResult to communicate with the database. It executes a query and I get the result. databaseRows contains the rows returned by this class. It is a List of an object that has the columnName and its value.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple enough to create a projection from the item that you have into an array of objects, where that array represents the values of a given collection of column names:

```
public static Func<DbResult, string[]> GetProperties(IEnumerable<string> propertyNames)
{
    return item => propertyNames.Select(name => item.Value(name))
        .ToArray();
}
```

The question is then how to group on an array of string values, as the default equality comparer will compare the references, not the values.  The comparer below will be able to compare sequences of values for equality based on the values in the sequence, instead of the identity of the sequence:

```
public class SequenceComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    private IEqualityComparer<T> comparer;
    public SequenceComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y, comparer);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 19;
            foreach (var item in sequence)
                hash = hash * 79 + comparer.GetHashCode(item);
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

So now we can write:

```
var query = databaseRows.GroupBy(GetProperties(columnsList), 
    new SequenceComparer<string>());
```